# Converting a stream into a URL

Tags: java, stream, uri

Is there any way to convert a stream in memory into an URL or URI object in java? 
I'm in a rather tricky spot where I'm forced to tamper with an XML coming from a URL due to some silly design issues from my counterpart team :( So i would like to change the XML using DOM or SAX and then convert it into an URL object.

I'm also aware that converting the stream to a File is sort of a direct solution(use the URL constructor). But i would rather avoid that expensive overhead.

Comment: "converting" you mean sending?

Comment: do you want something like `byte[] bytes = convertXmlInMemory(); URL url = createUrlForByteContent(bytes);`?

Comment: no i mean coverting in code. I am getting a wsdl(from an URL) which i need to edit in code using DOM and then use that edited Document as a URL( which is my problem). How do i convert that DOM object in memory into an URL.

Comment: What do you want to do with the URL? Pass it to someone other library. What will the receiver do with the URL?